# How to remove unwanted characters/text - php

Tags: php

When I retrieve a file, it outputs:

`...22nlarray(3) { [0]=> string(62) "/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/Albums/." [1]=> string(63) "/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/Albums/.." [2]=> string(69) "/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/Albums/22nl.mp3" }`

I, however, only want the 22nl displayed. I do not want the rest over there. How can I do that? Is there a function that deletes the rest of the output except 22nl (which is a filename)?

My PHP code:

```
   // get contents of the current directory
    $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $destination_folder);

   foreach ($contents as $mp3_url) { 
     $filename = basename($mp3_url, ".mp3");
     echo "<a href='$mp3_url'>$filename</a>";

 } 
     var_dump($contents);
```

There are similar questions to mine, however, they did not provide a good answer for me.
Greetings,

Rezoo Aftib

Comment: *"I, however, only want the 22nl displayed."* ... then why are you using `var_dump()` ? Everything you **don't want** appears to be the literal output from that function.

Comment: Write your comment as answer. It worked, I will accept it.

Comment: Please write your comment as a answer so people will know it is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can say that your value from the array will be

```
$value='string(69) "/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/Albums/22nl.mp3"';
```

So, you can make that to export your file name:

```
$value = explode('"',$value);
$exploded = explode('/', $value[1]);
$full_mp3_name = end($exploded);
$just_name = explode(".",$full_mp3_name);
$just_name = $just_name[0];
```

When you print $full_mp3_name you will need to have 22nl.mp3
When you print $just_name you will need to have 22nl

It will better with functions but its example if it will be option for you.

Comment: Works fine for me as well.